# Error executing mysql stored procedure on SQLSERVER linked server

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When executing a mysql sp through a linked server in SQLSERVER it throws the error:

`El proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' del servidor vinculado indica que el objeto no tiene columnas o el usuario actual no tiene permisos en ese objeto.`

I have both services (MariaDB 10.4 and SQLSERVER DEVELOPER) on my machine locally. I have delved into the internet a lot without having an accurate solution, that is why I turn to this great community, I hope you can help me.

I've tried configuring Ad Hoc Distributed Queries... but it still doesn't work, I've also tried this way `exec ('call SP_Bitacora("2011-03-31")') at <linkServer>` and it works but it would not work for me. would serve me `select * from openquery(<linkServer>` since in the select I need to do some calculations.

Comment: It would be good to also have a translation of the error messages in English.

Comment: And more details on your sp etc